# Is there a way to create key-value pairs in Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, associative-array

I am trying to create a dictionary of key value pair using Bash script. I am trying using this logic:

```
declare -d dictionary
defaults write "$dictionary" key -string "$value"
```

...where `$dictionary` is a variable, but this is not working.

Is there a way to create key-value pairs in Bash script?

Comment: i was working on bash. Figured a way to do this myself.

Comment: use of this also help:     urls+=( '<dict><key>key1</key><string>'$value1'</string><key>key2</key><string>'$value2'</string><key>key3</key><string>'$value3'</string></dict>'

Comment: Great! You're allowed (and even encouraged) to answer your own questions on StackOverflow, that way you'll help others in a similar situation.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

In bash version 4 associative arrays were introduced.

```
declare -A arr

arr["key1"]=val1

arr+=( ["key2"]=val2 ["key3"]=val3 )
```

The arr array now contains the three key value pairs. Bash is fairly limited what you can do with them though, no sorting or popping etc.

```
for key in ${!arr[@]}; do
    echo ${key} ${arr[${key}]}
done
```

Will loop over all key values and echo them out.

**Note:** Bash 4 does not come with Mac OS X because of its GPLv3 license; you have to download and install it. For more on that see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047648/bash-4-associative-arrays-error-declare-a-invalid-option)

Comment: It is important to note that Bash 4 does not come with Mac OS X because of its GPLv3 license; you have to download and install it. (Apple still ships Bash 3.2.)

Comment: There's a con here: The iteration is not ordered by insertion order.

Comment: definitely needs bash version 4. Otherwise declare -A does not work. Mac comes with bash 3.2

Comment: It's not because of the GPLv3 license but because Apple doesn't want to use GPLv3 licensed software. So it's nothing wrong with GPLv3 license but something wrong with Apple, I assume.

Answer (score 44):

If you can use a simple delimiter, a very simple oneliner is this:

```
for i in a,b c_s,d ; do 
  KEY=${i%,*};
  VAL=${i#*,};
  echo $KEY" XX "$VAL;
done
```

Hereby `i` is filled with character sequences like `"a,b"` and `"c_s,d"`. each separated by spaces. After the `do` we use [parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) to extract the part before the comma `,` and the part after it.

Comment: Can you please explain the example you gave?

Comment: Question: Will it work if `b` is a variable containing spaces?

Comment: in my example, b is not a variable, and no it will not work, as the list for the for-loop is space separated.

Answer (score 12):

In bash, we use

```sh
declare -A name_of_dictonary_variable
```

so that Bash understands it is a dictionary.

For e.g. you want to create `sounds` dictionary then,

```
declare -A sounds

sounds[dog]="Bark"

sounds[wolf]="Howl"
```

where `dog` and `wolf` are `"keys"`, and `Bark` and `Howl` are `"values"`.

You can access all values using : `echo ${sounds[@]}` OR `echo ${sounds[*]}`

You can access all keys only using: `echo ${!sounds[@]}`

And if you want any value for a particular key, you can use:

`${sounds[dog]}`

this will give you value (`Bark`) for key (`dog`).

Comment: I tried to run this ,I only get the last value
ie. echo "${sounds[dog]}" gives me Howl instead of Bark

Comment: PS-Got the issue,I was using 3.2.57. It works as said in bash 4+ versions

Answer (score 4):

For persistent key/value storage, you can use `kv-bash`, a pure bash implementation of key/value database available at https://github.com/damphat/kv-bash

**Usage**

```
git clone https://github.com/damphat/kv-bash
source kv-bash/kv-bash
```

**Try create some permanent variables**

```
kvset myName  xyz
kvset myEmail xyz@example.com

#read the varible
kvget myEmail

#you can also use in another script with $(kvget keyname)
echo $(kvget myEmail)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Using an example above this is what I did

#!/bin/sh
lookup_vht_index() {
for i in VHT20,0 VHT40,1 VHT80,2 VHT160,3 ; do
  KEY=${i%,*};
  VAL=${i#*,};
#  echo $KEY" XX "$VAL;
  [ "$1" = "$KEY" ] && echo $VAL
done
}

lookup_vht_name() {
for i in 0,VHT20 1,VHT40 2,VHT80 3,VHT160 ; do
  KEY=${i%,*};
  VAL=${i#*,};
#  echo $KEY" XX "$VAL;
  [ "$1" = "$KEY" ] && echo $VAL
done
}


echo "VHT20="$(lookup_vht_index "VHT20")
echo "2="$(lookup_vht_name 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

in older bash (or in `sh`) that does not support `declare -A`, following style can be used to emulate key/value

```
# key
env=staging


# values
image_dev=gcr.io/abc/dev
image_staging=gcr.io/abc/stage
image_production=gcr.io/abc/stable

img_var_name=image_$env

# active_image=${!var_name}
active_image=$(eval "echo \$$img_var_name")

echo $active_image
```