# bash read strings and output as one key and multiple values

Tags: bash, dictionary, key

Assuming there is an input:

```
1,2,C
```

We are trying to output it as

```
KEY=1, VAL1=2, VAL2=C
```

So far trying to modify from here: 
[Is there a way to create key-value pairs in Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370133/is-there-a-way-to-create-key-value-pairs-in-bash-script)

```
for i in 1,2,C ; do KEY=${i%,*,*}; VAL1=${i#*,}; VAL2=${i#*,*,}; echo $KEY" XX "$VAL1 XX "$VAL2"; done
```

Output:

```
1 XX 2,c XX c
```

Not entirely sure what the pound ("#") and % here mean above, making the modification kinda hard.

Could any guru enlighten?  Thanks.

Comment: Here is the syntax explanation: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073

Comment: btw, for this case, your code can be shortened to: `IFS=, read KEY VAL1 VAL2 <<< "1,2,C"`

Comment: hi anishsane, your answer is BRILLIANT!

Comment: Byw, I don't see the page explains % and #?

Comment: Surely that page explains it. Do check  [BashFAQ73](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) & [BashFAQ100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Substituting_part_of_a_string) (which is liked in the first page - FAQ#73) They should be sufficient to explain what `%` & `#` do in above syntax.

Comment: IFS=, read KEY VAL1 VAL2 <<< "1,2,c"; echo $KEY" XX "$VAL1 XX "$VAL2" works fine in the bash command line.  However, if I put this command into a .sh file and execute, an error message "Syntax error: redirection unexpected" will pop out.   May I know the reason? tHANKS

Comment: @Chubaka: Try adding the line `#!/bin/bash` in the beginning of your script. The error is likely due to the redirection operator `<<<`  not available in your native shell (`/bin/sh` maybe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generally prefer easier to read code, as bash can get ugly pretty fast.

Try this:

**key_values.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=,
count=0
# $* is the expansion of all the params passed in, i.e. $1, $2, $3, ...
for i in $*; do
    # '-eq' is checking for equality, i.e. is $count equal to zero.
    if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -n "KEY=$i"
    else
        echo -n ", VAL${count}=$i"
    fi
    count=$(( $count + 1 ))
done

echo
```

**Example**

```
key_values.sh 1,2,ABC,123,DEF
```

**Output**

```
KEY=1, VAL1=2, VAL2=ABC, VAL3=123, VAL4=DEF
```

Comment: Looks good! but not quite sure what "$*" and "-eq" means.  Could you enlighten?

Comment: Added some comments.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on anishsane's comment:

```
$ echo $1
1,2,3,4,5

$ IFS=, read -ra args <<<"$1"     # read into an array

$ out="KEY=${args[0]}"

$ for ((i=1; i < ${#args[@]}; i++)); do out+=", VAL$i=${args[i]}"; done

$ echo "$out"
KEY=1, VAL1=2, VAL2=3, VAL3=4, VAL4=5
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!