# Combining key value pairs in bash from two lists in text files

Tags: bash, dictionary, key-value

I'm looking for a solution in bash to rename multiple fastq files in a bioinformatics pipeline in a for loop, or something similar. The information is contained in two lists.

List A

```
SRR11111111
SRR11111112
SRR11111113
SRR11111114
SRR11111115
```

List B

```
Sample1
Sample2
Sample3
Sample4
Sample5
```

I need to change the names of the fastq files from those contained in list A to the names in list B. So the fastq file named `SRR11111111` (position 1 in list A) becomes `sample1` (position 1 in list B) and so on. Although, the loop below is nonsense, it gives you an idea of what I want to do.

```
for file in listA
do

mv listA[position] listB[position]

done
```

In other packages such as python I would use a dictionary for this, using key-value pairs, or use a config file but not sure of the most efficient method to do this in bash.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370133/is-there-a-way-to-create-key-value-pairs-in-bash-script) is similar but not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `paste` in a process substitution:

```
while read -r old new; do
   echo mv "$old" "$new"
done < <(paste listA listB)
```

```
mv SRR11111111 Sample1
mv SRR11111112 Sample2
mv SRR11111113 Sample3
mv SRR11111114 Sample4
mv SRR11111115 Sample5
```

When you're satisfied with output, remove `echo` before `mv`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use following `awk` too here.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next} {system("echo mv " a[FNR] OFS $0)}' ListA ListB
```

Remove `echo` in above code once you are satisfied with commands printed over screen.

Answer (score 2):

```
while IFS= read -r fileA && IFS= read -ru 3 fileB; do
    mv -- "$fileA" "$fileB"
done < listA 3< listB
```