# What is the difference between "#!/usr/bin/env bash" and "#!/usr/bin/bash"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, shebang

In the header of a Bash script, what's the difference between those two statements:

1. `#!/usr/bin/env bash`
2. `#!/usr/bin/bash`

When I consulted the `env` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/env), I get this definition:

```
 env - run a program in a modified environment
```

What does it mean?

Comment: See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) and [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454).

Comment: Who can tell me why this question is closed, " related to programming or software development" isen't ?

Comment: I agree that it's not off-topic, but it's probably a duplicate of several other questions such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2429511/827263).

Comment: This question should not have been marked as off-topic. It just needs 5 people with above a score of 3000 to mark it as "on-topic" and it can be reopened. It is a question - specifically about programming.

Comment: @DanijelJ: I agree that it's not off-topic, but it is a duplicate. We could vote to reopen and then vote to close it again as a duplicate. It hardly seems worth the effort.

Comment: Related: [Why is #!/usr/bin/env bash superior to #!/bin/bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21612980/55075) at SO

Comment: I'm shocked. Shocked to find that Linux documentation is rife with tautologies. https://xkcd.com/703/ http://git-man-page-generator.lokaltog.net/

Comment: One major difference is that, depending on the system, `#!/usr/bin/bash` **won't work**. On my system (Ubuntu 17.04), `bash` is `/bin/bash`, and there is no `/usr/bin/bash`. The distinction between `/bin` and `/usr/bin` is largely arbitrary. And just to add to the frivolity, most systems put the `env` command in `/usr/bin`, but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: then symlink it. But it most definitely WAS on topic.

Answer (score 506, accepted):

Running a command through `/usr/bin/env` has the benefit of looking for whatever the default version of the program is in your current **env**ironment.

This way, you don't have to look for it in a specific place on the system, as those paths may be in different locations on different systems.  As long as it's in your path, it will find it.

One downside is that you will be unable to pass more than one argument (e.g. you will be unable to write `/usr/bin/env awk -f`) if you wish to support Linux, as [POSIX is vague](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399702/6252) on how the line is to be interpreted, and Linux interprets everything after the first space to denote a single argument. You can use `/usr/bin/env -S` on some versions of `env` to get around this, but then the script will become even less portable and break on fairly recent systems (e.g. even Ubuntu 16.04 if not later).

Another downside is that since you aren't calling an explicit executable, it's got the potential for mistakes, and on multiuser systems security problems (if someone managed to get their executable called `bash` in your path, for example).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash #lends you some flexibility on different systems
#!/usr/bin/bash     #gives you explicit control on a given system of what executable is called
```

In some situations, the first may be preferred (like running python scripts with multiple versions of python, without having to rework the executable line).  But in situations where security is the focus, the latter would be preferred, as it limits code injection possibilities.

Comment: Another drawback is that you can't pass an additional argument to the interpreter.

Comment: @KeithThompson : Incorrect info.. You can pass options to the underlying interpreter using /usr/bin/env!

Comment: @GauravAgarwal: Not on my system. A script containing just this single line: `#!/usr/bin/env echo Hello` complains: `/usr/bin/env: echo Hello: No such file or directory`. Apparently it treats `echo Hello` as a single argument to `/usr/bin/env`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Could you provide more info about your system?

Comment: @KeithThompson, the GNU Coreutils version of `env` allows args to be passed to the command. The FreeBSD env also [seems to support it](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=env). What are you using? :)

Comment: @AndréLaszlo: The `env` command certainly allows arguments to be passed to the command. The issue is the semantics of the `#!` line, and that depends on the kernel. Recent Linux kernels do allow things like `#!/usr/bin/env command args`, but older Linux kernels and other systems don't.

Comment: Yeah, I just tested. Sorry, should have read your comment more carefully :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306518/cannot-pass-an-argument-to-python-with-usr-bin-env-python

Comment: Why are there backticks in the code block? Shouldn't they be removed?

Comment: Made the command stand out more?  Honestly, it was four years ago, so I don't have a legit excuse.  In a shell script, you're correct, they wouldn't be there, and admittedly I didn't dig in to SE markup as much back then.

Comment: A note: there is an assumption that env should be in /usr/bin/env in the most of systems. In many of them, bash is in /bin/bash, so the use of /usr/bin/env maybe just a small flexibility... another note is that in some (old?) systems, /usr is a different partition that can be not mounted, and maybe for that cause #!/bin/bash is usually used, not #!/usr/bin/bash

Comment: I've had problems with using env in my scripts and then adding those scripts to a crontab.  Even running under the same user, the environment is different when executing it in the shell and it getting executed by cron.  My script didn't run as a cron job.  I think this is worth mentioning in this excellent answer.

Comment: I don't see how `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is less secure. As I understand it, if an attacker has the necessary access to perform an attack against `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, they would also be able to perform a similar attack against a `#!/bin/bash` script simply by adding malicious versions of `echo`, `grep`, and the like to your `PATH`. To fully mitigate the risk of this sort of attack you'd have to always use absolute paths for executables, but that defeats the purpose of having a `PATH` at all.

Answer (score 122):

Using `#!/usr/bin/env NAME` makes the shell search for the first match of NAME in the $PATH environment variable.  It can be useful if you aren't aware of the absolute path or don't want to search for it.

Comment: At least you have to know where env is :).

Comment: Excellent answer. Explains succinctly what the env shebang does, rather than saying "chooses the program based on your system configuration"

Comment: Here is the situation I encountered. When I run the command "./script.sh" with "#!/usr/bin/env bash" in the first line of script.sh, it gives a feedback of "-bash: ./tools/dist_train.sh: Permission denied".  When I run the command "bash ./script.sh". It can work well. Could you tell me why "#!/usr/bin/env NAME" doesn't work...?

Comment: @EricKani: Most likely your `"./script.sh"` does have its executable flag unchecked (so you can't execute it on its own). `"bash ./script.sh"` happily accepts non-executable script files. (Solution: `chmod +x ./script.sh`)

Answer (score 70):

If the shell scripts start with `#!/bin/bash`, they will always run with `bash` from `/bin`. If they however start with `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, they will search for `bash` in `$PATH` and then start with the first one they can find.

Why would this be useful? Assume you want to run `bash` scripts, that require bash 4.x or newer, yet your system only has `bash` 3.x installed and currently your distribution doesn't offer a newer version or you are no administrator and cannot change what is installed on that system.

Of course, you can download bash source code and build your own bash from scratch, placing it to `~/bin` for example. And you can also modify your `$PATH` variable in your `.bash_profile` file to include `~/bin` as the first entry (`PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH` as `~` will not expand in `$PATH`). If you now call `bash`, the shell will first look for it in `$PATH` in order, so it starts with `~/bin`, where it will find your `bash`. Same thing happens if scripts search for `bash` using `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, so these scripts would now be working on your system using your custom `bash` build.

One downside is, that this can lead to unexpected behavior, e.g. same script on the same machine may run with different interpreters for different environments or users with different search paths, causing all kind of headaches.

The biggest downside with `env` is that some systems will only allow one argument, so you cannot do this `#!/usr/bin/env <interpreter> <arg>`, as the systems will see `<interpreter> <arg>` as one argument (they will treat it as if the expression was quoted) and thus `env` will search for an interpreter named `<interpreter> <arg>`. Note that this is not a problem of the `env` command itself, which always allowed multiple parameters to be passed through but with the shebang parser of the system that parses this line before even calling `env`. Meanwhile this has been fixed on most systems but if your script wants to be ultra portable, you cannot rely that this has been fixed on the system you will be running.

It can even have security implications, e.g. if `sudo` was not configured to clean environment or `$PATH` was excluded from clean up. Let me demonstrate this:

Usually `/bin` is a well protected place, only `root` is able to change anything there. Your home directory is not, though, any program you run is able to make changes to it. That means malicious code could place a fake `bash` into some hidden directory, modify your `.bash_profile` to include that directory in your `$PATH`, so all scripts using `#!/usr/bin/env bash` will end up running with that fake `bash`. If `sudo` keeps `$PATH`, you are in big trouble.

E.g. consider a tool creates a file `~/.evil/bash` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $EUID -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "All your base are belong to us..."
  # We are root - do whatever you want to do
fi

/bin/bash "$@"
```

Let's make a simple script `sample.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Hello World"
```

Proof of concept (on a system where `sudo` keeps `$PATH`):

```
$ ./sample.sh
Hello World

$ sudo ./sample.sh
Hello World

$ export PATH="$HOME/.evil:$PATH"

$ ./sample.sh
Hello World

$ sudo ./sample.sh
All your base are belong to us...
Hello World
```

Usually the classic shells should all be located in `/bin` and if you don't want to place them there for whatever reason, it's really not an issue to place a symlink in `/bin` that points to their real locations (or maybe `/bin` itself is a symlink), so I would always go with `#!/bin/sh` and `#!/bin/bash`. There's just too much that would break if these wouldn't work anymore. It's not that POSIX would require these position (POSIX does not standardize path names and thus it doesn't even standardize the shebang feature at all) but they are so common, that even if a system would not offer a `/bin/sh`, it would probably still understand `#!/bin/sh` and know what to do with it and may it only be for compatibility with existing code.

But for more modern, non standard, optional interpreters like Perl, PHP, Python, or Ruby, it's not really specified anywhere where they should be located. They may be in `/usr/bin` but they may as well be in `/usr/local/bin` or in a completely different hierarchy branch (`/opt/...`, `/Applications/...`, etc.). That's why these often use the `#!/usr/bin/env xxx` shebang syntax.

Comment: Thanks @Mecki, best answer by far, especially by demonstrating how easy it is to include the "All your base are belong to us..." part. A real black hat hacker would not add that part and only would try to exploit any vulnerabilities (be they technically or personally - see social engineering) I use the shebangs #!/bin/sh and #!/bin/bash - and if someone complains I tell them to either edit the script themselves or create a symlink in /bin - or ask their system administrator to create the symlinks in /bin .

Comment: Good answer.  This is basically why it is a very bad practice to put `.` in your `PATH`, in the first place.  Even if you have it in the last position in `PATH`, at it later might not be last any longer.

Answer (score 16):

Instead of explicitly defining the path to the interpreter as in `/usr/bin/bash/`, by using the env command, the interpreter is searched for and launched from wherever it is first found.  This has both [upsides and downsides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env)

Comment: On most systems, they will be functionally the same, but it depends on the location of your bash and env executables.  Not sure how this will affect environment variables, though.

Comment: "It is possible to specify the interpreter without using env, by giving the full path to the interpreter. A problem is that on different computer systems, the exact path may be different. By instead using env, the interpreter is searched for and located at the time the script is run. This makes the script more portable, but also increases the risk that the wrong interpreter is selected because it searches for a match in every directory on the executable search path. It also suffers from the same problem in that the path to the env binary may also be different on a per-machine basis."-Wikipedia

Answer (score 4):

I find it useful, because when I didn't know about env, before I started to write script I was doing this:

```
type nodejs > scriptname.js #or any other environment
```

and then I was modifying that line in the file into shebang.
I was doing this, because I didn't always remember where is nodejs on my computer -- /usr/bin/ or /bin/, so for me `env` is very useful. Maybe there are details with this, but this is my reason

Answer (score 2):

One reason is that it is portable across both Linux and BSD.

Comment: Could help with an example why it makes it portable.  It is not only for compatibility between Linux and BSD but also between different distributions of Linux.  But yes, you are right.

Comment: I found the reference to it when I needed to port to BSD. I verified it empirically on a couple of Linux distros. For BSD, it was tried on GhostBSD and Mac (which is a linux port of sorts). Obviously not a very satisfying answer.