# simple cp $file1 $file2 script not working?

Tags: bash, file, cp

I tried searching for this question but I couldn't find a thread specifically like this one. I am trying to do a practice script where you enter in a source and a destination and the program copies the files for you.

```
./testscript
"name of file to copy?"       file1
"to be copied to?"            file2
"file1 has been copied to file2"
```

So far I have this:

```
#!bin/bash
echo -e 'Enter file name of file you wish to copy'
read $FILE1
echo -e 'Enter the file you wish to copy to'
read $FILE2
if cp $FILE1 $FILE2
    then echo -e 'Copy was successful'
else echo -e 'Copy was unsuccessful'
fi
```

The program error is saying bad interpreter. I don't really understand, it looks okay from my end.

Comment: such a stupid mistake, thank you. I might have to work on the script since it's finding a problem with my code. "Missing File Operand"

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: `read FILE1` and `read FILE2` -- the argument to `read` is the *name* of a parameter, not its value. As a result, `FILE1` and `FILE2` are never set for the `cp` command.

Answer (score 0):

The path you supplied as interpreter is not absolute (missing '/').
I suggest changing `#!bin/bash` to `#!/usr/bin/env bash`
.
See [The difference between "#! /usr/bin/env bash" and "#! /usr/bin/bash"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365130/the-difference-between-usr-bin-env-bash-and-usr-bin-bash) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided incorrect path to the interpreter. You are probably missing a forward slash in the beginning.

The shebang statement should say: #!/bin/bash (or whatever the correct path is)