# Variable Syntax Error with Bash Script (Homework)

Tags: bash

I'm currently working on homework for a Unix course and I've got everything else done but I just can't figure out what I've done wrong here. I've done this exact same script in csh (but we need to do it in bash as well.) I've already fixed a few errors but now the one I'm getting is "Variable Syntax" when I try to run it.

I've tried using double brackets for the while and ifs
I've also tried declaring the variables for the inputs before I try to read to them
I've also tried bugging several people in my class but most of them are pretty clueless and just copy off others.

```
#/!bin/bash
#
#Menunix - Bash
#
#Usage: menunixb
input = "$(1)" 
while [ $input != 5 ]
do
    echo Please choose an option
    echo 1: List Files 
    echo 2: Display today's date and time
    echo 3: Check whether a file is a directory or not
    echo 4: Create a file backup
    echo 5: Quit
    read input
    case $input in
        1) 
            ls
            ;;
        2)
            echo -n Time:
            date +"%T"
            echo Date:
            date +"%D"
            ;;
        3)
            echo What file do you wish to check
            read finput
            if [ -d $finput ] ; then
                echo $finput is a Directory
            elif [ -f $finput ] ; then
            echo $finput is a File
            else
                echo $finput does not exist
                ;;
            4)
                echo Please enter filename to backup
                read binput
                cp $binput{,.bak}
                ;;
            5)
                exit 1
            *)
                echo Please choose a valid input
                exit 1
            esac
        done
#EOF
```

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting of your code.  Hint: quotes

Comment: Consider to use indentation. This makes the code much more readable and thus easier to debug.

Answer (score 3):

You must fix the quotes around the `echo` statements.

```
echo 2: Display today's date and time
```

is particularly wrong because it opens a quotation, but never closes it. Try quoting all those echo lines:

```
echo "2: Display today's date and time"
```

Spoiler: I was bored and [refactored this](https://gist.github.com/kojiromike/9796486). Feel free to use it to research a different way to do things in the shell. It may involve features you haven't been introduced to in your class, but you may find it helpful anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at:

```
input = "$(1)"
```

You notice the spaces around the equal sign (=)? This [is not allowed](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/newbie_traps#setting_variables) in bash. It has to be

```
input="$(1)"
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: As the OP discovered, another issue was a malformed shebang line: `#/!bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/bash` (consider using `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, though).

A tip beforehand: http://shellcheck.net is a very handy tool for checking shell code for errors.

---

@Ube and @kojiro's answers both contain important pointers:

- `'` is used for quoting, so it must either be used inside *double* quotes, or it must be escaped as `\'`.
- No spaces are allowed around the `=` in variable assignments in `bash`.

But there's more:

- Use `$1` to refer to the first argument; `$(1)` does something fundamentally different: it uses command substitution (`$(...)`) to execute the enclosed command and return its stdout output; thus, `$(1)` tries to execute a - most likely non-existent - command `1` and return its output.
- Always use `[[ ... ]]` rather than `[ ...]` in bash; it's more robust and provides more features; case in point: `[ $input != 5 ]` will *break* if `$input` is undefined or empty - you'd have to double-quote it to prevent that; by contrast, it's fine to use `[[ $input != 5 ]]`.
- *All* `case` branches must be terminated with `;;` (even the branches that just contain `exit` commands;).<sup>Fine print: the very last branch also works without `;;`</sup>
- The `if [ -d $finput ] ; then ...` statement is missing its closing `fi`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is actually on the interpreter line:

```
#/!bin/bash
```

is not the same as

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Once I actually had the script running in bash it was just a few minor syntax errors and I was done.

Comment: :) Note that in order to be slightly more portable and respect the user's choice of bash interpreter, some prefer `#!/usr/bin/env bash` - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16365367/45375 for pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

I indented the code for you. You have a few issues:

- Always use quotation marks around echo statements. You can't use words like `today's` or else you're starting to quote everything to the end of your file.
- Use indents. I indented your code as it appeared on my editor. Notice something? You're missing a `fi` to end an if statement.

What type of system are you on? You should always use a real live program editor. I dope slap developers who use Notepad at my work.

- You can always use [VIM](http://vim.org) on any platform. It comes on Linux and Mac and is downloadable on Windows. Does automatic indenting and syntax highlighting which would have caught your incomplete `if` statement and your `today's` error.
- VIM can be a bit daunting. It's powerful, but hard to learn. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) is a easy to use program editor with syntax highlighting and auto indenting.
- On Mac, try [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) which is free and includes syntax highlighting and auto indenting. You can also use Xcode which comes for free with Mac OS X.
- On Linux, you're on your own. Most Linux people use either VIM, EMACs, or Eclipse. Kate is popular, but is a KDE application. I've seen a few people use BlueFish. Most are free, easy to install, and are open source.
- A *not so* secret trick. Put `set -xv` in your code. It'll print out the lines being executed and the result once the shell interpolates that line. You can even set the `PS4` prompt to `\$LINENO:` which will print out the line number of your shell script too. This is a great debugging aid. To turn off the verbose debugging, use `set +xv`.