# Bash script file hangs on execute

Tags: bash, debian, lamp

I just realized that i cannot execute .sh scripts anymore on my debian.
It used to work fine. All .sh files are +x chmodded and used to work fine.
Suddenly, once i execute: `./test.sh` system hangs.
I am able to stop this via ctrl+c, but script never executes.

Steps did so far was to restart my VPS.
Any ideas?

Comment: Obvious question: what does `test.sh` do? What are the contents of the script?

Comment: They are all .sh scripts by Tuxlite LAMP script.

The one i execute now is:
http://pastebin.com/ntK6A0M0

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure shell scripts are still working on your machine, because if they weren't, you would not be able to complete any boot cycle.

If I suppose you are facing problems with your homemade scripts, then you should probably check your shebang line (#!/bin/sh for example) to see if anything unusual was used there.

```
New scripts are using a dispatcher to interpreters: 
`#!/usr/bin/env bash` #lends you some flexibility on different systems
`#!/usr/bin/bash`     #gives you explicit control on a given system of what executable is called
```

[The difference between “#! /usr/bin/env bash” and “#! /usr/bin/bash”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365130/the-difference-between-usr-bin-env-bash-and-usr-bin-bash)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, they seem to work. It hangs on all .sh scripts of a LAMP that i use. Contents of one of them can be found here: http://pastebin.com/ntK6A0M0

Comment: If all are hanging on the start I would verify the line «source ./options.conf» (the content of options.conf).

Comment: It still hangs if I execute source ./options.conf. Options file is there.

Comment: So, what I suspect is that the code on ./options.conf has the problem.