# How to execute a PHP script from the command line by just typing the file name?

Tags: php, command-line

I want to be able to type into the command line, and have the following PHP script execute like so:

```
$ hello.php
```

Question is, where do I save my `hello.php` file to run it like this. I see a lot of tutorials showing this way, but they do not mention where to save the actual file. If I save it on my desktop then it will run when I type in:

```
~/Desktop/hello.php
```

I want to be able to just type in the file name regardless of what directory I'm in and have it execute.

Do I have to setup an alias? Or can I just put it in a specific folder.

**hello.php**

```
<?php

echo 'Hello! This is a test';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is add a [*shebang line*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

echo 'Hello! This is a test';
```

And then:

```
chmod +x hello.php
```

Then you can run it from the same directory by just typing:

```
./hello.php
```

If you want to be able to run it from anywhere, put it somewhere in `$PATH`, such as `/usr/local/bin`. You can either actually put the file there, or [change your PATH](https://superuser.com/questions/488173/how-can-i-edit-the-path-on-linux), or [create a symbolic link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-creating-symbolic-link-ln-command/). Then, you can run it as:

```
hello.php
```

Answer (score 2):

1. add a shebang to your executable file.
2. `chmod +x file_name.php` to make it runnable.

just like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
var_dump($argv);
?>
```

this one is a bit better (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365130/the-difference-between-usr-bin-env-bash-and-usr-bin-bash)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
var_dump($argv);
?>
```