# How to create/register command with php file(without extension)?

Tags: php, bash, command-line-interface

Well i want create command and register it on Linux/Mac/Windows
For example, i want use `$ ownco create project hello`

But `ownc` is php script like this(`ownco.php` or `ownco`):

```
<?php
if (count($argv) > 3) {
    echo 'Hi';
} else {
    echo 'Ups!';
}
```

I dont want use `php ownco ...`
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add a shebang at the first line of your file, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

Make the file executable:

```
chmod +x ./ownco.php
```

Now you can run the script from the command line without specifying the interpreter:

```
% ./path/to/ownco.php
Ups!
```

But to avoid having to write the full path to `ownco.php` you will need to keep it in a directory that are specified in your `$PATH` variable, this usually looks something like this:

```
% echo "$PATH"
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

You can see each directory is seperated by `:`. You can either move your script to one of these directories or add a new directory to the `$PATH` variable. Usually this is done my adding a bit of code to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/my/new/place/to/keep/executables"
```

Some people like to create a `bin` directory in their home directory, and keep small script there.

```
% cat ~/.bashrc
...
...
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
...
...


% cat > ~/bin/script1 <<EOL
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo("my first script\n");
?>
EOL
% chmod +x ~/bin/script1
% script1
my first script
```

Notes:

The shebang can be specified on the first line of executable files and start with `#!`.

I choose to use `/usr/bin/php` as the executable. This is the path for where PHP is stored.

Some people like to use `/usr/bin/env php` which will run the version of PHP which are specified in your `$PATH` variable. [See more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365130/the-difference-between-usr-bin-env-bash-and-usr-bin-bash)