# different results between crontab and running script manually

Tags: bash, cron, network-programming, nmap

I have a bash script that does this:

```
nmap -sn 192.168.0.1-255 | grep -Eo 192.168.0.{1,3\}[0-9] > new.txt
date >> network_log
echo ---------------------------- >> network_log
cat new.txt >> network_log
```

Scans the network, and appends results to file network_log with a timestamp.
After running it manually, the network_log file looks like this:

```
Tue 13 Sep 2016 11:22:23 EDT 
---------------------------- 

192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2 
192.168.0.45
```

whereas the cronjobs produce the following outputs in my network_log file:

```
Tue Sep 13 17:46:00 EDT 2016
----------------------------
```

with no ip results.
Note: the cronjob is running from root user so it has all the elevation it needs to scan the entire network.

Comment: have you tried your script with `sudo` to see if it's the cron or root user which makes a difference?

Comment: I am actually running the script from both sudo cron and regular cron, and they are both producing the same incorrect output. I ran my script manually using sudo & regular mode, they produce the same correct output.

Comment: check environment variable differences. And I would do `grep -Eo '192\.168\.0\.{1,3\}[0-9]'` (quoting)

Comment: attempting to try that... getting this error for some reason: "grep: invalid repetition count(s)"

Comment: Do you put those commands in crontab directly or you just call the script?

Comment: Do you have other cronjobs that write to `new.txt`?

Comment: Check the path to `nmap` with `type map` or `which nmap` and put the full path in your script.

Comment: @Leon just saw these now, I call the script from the cronjob, and no others write to new.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there are a couple of problems in your grep regular expression:

1. The repetition count (`{1,3}`) applies to its preceding atom (i.e. '`.`') rather than the next one (i.e. '`[0-9]`').
2. An unescaped dot ('`.`') in the regex matches any character, which hides the previous error. Your regex  (`192.168.0.{1,3}[0-9]`) matches `192.168.0.123` as follows:

   ```
   192.168.0 matches 192.168.0
   .{1,3}    matches .12
   [0-9]     matches 3
   ```

   But it would also match the following strings:

   ```
   192116810abc1
   192.681.012.9
   ```

The correct regex must be `192\.168\.0\.[0-9]{1,3}` and it must be quoted, so that bash passes it to grep literally:

```
grep -Eo '192\.168\.0\.[0-9]{1,3}'
```

Yet, the wrong regex can hardly explain the problem your are seeing with cron.

One problem may be that you are using a fixed name `new.txt` for your temporary file. If you do the same in your other scripts, or if you set up this cron job to run every minute while it takes `nmap` more than a minute to complete scanning the network, then `new.txt` may be overwritten at the wrong time.

Please fix your script as follows and check if the problem disappears:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmpfile="$(mktemp)"
trap "rm $tmpfile" EXIT
nmap -sn 192.168.0.1-255 | grep -Eo '192\.168\.0\.[0-9]{1,3}' > "$tmpfile"
date >> network_log
echo ---------------------------- >> network_log
cat "$tmpfile" >> network_log
```

Comment: Thank-you for all these suggestions, I would have never realized the tmpfile thing is alot better, especially since nmap does take a relatively long time to run. & thankyou for regex corrections

Answer (score 6):

Your script lacks a shebang, so it might run with different shells depending on a crontab or manual launch.

Add the following as first line in your script (replace bash with your current user shell if needed):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Don't use /bin/bash as it's less portable than /usr/bin/env bash.

Also, crontab runs won't have the PATH variable.
Print your path variable with:

```
echo $PATH
```

And add it as second line of your script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

This should ensure that your script runs in the same environment when run by crontab or manually.

Comment: Thanks for this! It works now, could you provide me with a link or expand on why /bin/bash is less portable than /usr/bin/env bash

Comment: /bin/bash is linux specific whereas /usr/bin/env is supposed to exist on all unix systems. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365130/the-difference-between-usr-bin-env-bash-and-usr-bin-bash for mre.