# How do I have a variable in a bash script correspond to the url in wget

Tags: bash, loops, curl, wget

For example, I have a bash script named `getimage`. In the script I have:

```
wget http://www.example.com/images/1.jpg
```

If I type `bash getimage` in the terminal, it would download the picture.

But what I want is to type `bash getimage 2` or `bash getimage 3` and so on in the terminal and download `2.jpg` or `3.jpg` respectively.

Basically, I want to type a number in terminal (`bash getimage number`) and have it correspond to `wget http://www.example.com/images/number.jpg`.

Comment: You want to be able to pass a parameter to your script that you will be able to reference from that script. To that effect, you can use positional parameters, that will be referenced from the script as `$1`, `$2`, etc. In your case only `$1` is necessary, and you could change your command to `wget "http://www.example.com/images/$1.jpg"`

Comment: Also instead of calling `bash getimage` you could add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to your script so that just calling `getimage` does the same.

Comment: Thanks so much, Aaron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Aaron mentioned in comments, you need to give the variables externally by specifying them as `$1` or `$2` etc in your script.

The way to do this is-

`wget http://www.example.com/images/"$1".jpg`

Then launch your script as `bash getimage 1`

If (as I suspect) you want to `wget` in a loop, do-

```
for i in {1..10} ; do bash getimage "$i" ; done
```

Or from the commandline,

```
for i in {1..10} ; do wget http://www.example.com/images/"$i".jpg ; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do :

```
#!/bin/bash
image_name=${1-1}
wget "http://www.example.com/images/$image_name.jpg"
```

The script is to be called as `getimage x`. If `x` is omitted, `1` will be chosen as a default value.

The first line is a shebang : it tells your shell to execute the script with the specified executable, `/bin/bash`.

The second line defines an `image_name` variable and assigns it the result of an expression. That expression is a parameter expansion, which will return `$1` (that is the first parameter passed to the script) if it is defined, or `1` either. It's hard to see in this case, but the syntax is `${variable-default}` where `variable` is a variable name whose value you want, and `default` a default used when that variable isn't defined.

The third line is your command, where the static `1` has been replaced by a reference to the `image_name` variable. Note that `""` have been added in case the `image_name` contains spaces : that would break the url in two parts that would be understood by `wget` as two separate parameters. Don't use `''` though, the `$variable` contained in the string wouldn't be expanded to their value.

Answer (score 2):

A minimal script for what you want would be the following.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
wget "http://www.example.com/images/${1}.jpg"
```

The first line is called a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) The shebang tells the script which program to run it in. In this case we use the [env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365130/the-difference-between-usr-bin-env-bash-and-usr-bin-bash) program to find the default version of bash in the current environment.

On the second line we simply run your `wget` command, but we pass in the variable `$1`. This is a special variable called a [positional parameter](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams), in this case the first argument passed to the script.

To run the command, make it executable with `chmod +x getimage` and then call it like so:

```
./getimage 1
./getimage 2
etc.
```