# bash script to dynamically display array element based on user selection(s)

Tags: arrays, bash

i have to task to write a bash script which can let user to choose which array element(s) to display.

for example, the array have these element

**ARRAY=(zero one two three four five six)**

i want the script to be able to print out the element after user enter the array index

let say the user entered(in one line) :  **1 2 6 5**

then the output will be : **one two six five**

the index entered can be single(input: **0** output: **zero**) or multiple(such as above) and the output will be correspond to the index(es) entered

any help is much appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ARRAY=(zero one two three four five six)
for i in $@; do
    echo -n ${ARRAY[$i]}
done
echo
```

Then call this script like this:

```
script.sh 1 2 6 5
```

it will print:

```
one two six five
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use associative arrays for a generic solution, i.e. assuming your keys aren't just integers:

```
# syntax for declaring an associative array
declare -A myArray
# to quickly assign key value store
myArray=([1]=one [2]=two [3]=three)
# or to assign them one by one
myArray[4]='four'
# you can use strings as key values
myArray[five]=5
# Using them is straightforward
echo ${myArray[3]} # three
# Assuming input in $@
for i in 1 2 3 4 five; do
    echo -n ${myArray[$i]}
done
# one two three four 5
```

Also, make sure you're using Bash4 (version 3 doesn't support it). See [this answer and comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047948/800207) for more details.

Comment: There's nothing in the question that requires an associative array.

Comment: Agreed, I edited to the answer to reflect a generic solution