# Is it possible to compile Bash 5 without support for associative arrays?

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew, configure

My colleague that tested my bash script sent me this screenshot

[image: bash5 without associative arrays]

He installed `bash` from brew. Is it possible that `declare` has no `-A` option in `bash:5` ?

I checked same with docker, `bash:5` must have `-A`:

```
$ docker run -it bash:5
bash-5.0# declare -A
declare -A BASH_ALIASES=()
declare -A BASH_CMDS=()
```

Screenshot is similar to `bash:3` output, when there is no [associative arrays support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494178/how-to-define-hash-tables-in-bash/3467959#3467959):

```
$ docker run -it bash:3
bash-3.2# declare -A
bash: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
```

Is it possible to compile `bash:5` without associative arrays support ?

[Here](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/bash#default) is page of `bash` package in homebrew, I haven't found any any special options in `./configure` section of Formula ruby installation script.

Comment: Could it be [this scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43948526/3266847)?

Comment: As in, your script has a `#!/bin/bash` hashbang line, which hardcodes the system Bash.

Comment: Probably you are right, I know that on MacOS default bash version is 3. I'm not using MacOS, but wouldn't system Bash changed after installing via `brew` ?

Comment: The first bash in the `PATH` will be the new one, typically at `usr/local/bin/bash`, but `/bin/bash` is unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I added `#!/usr/bin/env bash` instead of `#!/bin/bash` and direct checking version via `if [ "${BASH_VERSINFO:-0}" -lt 4 ]; then` for more portability :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question "can you compile Bash without support for associative arrays": there is a [`configure` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Optional-Features) `--enable-array-variables`, which I strongly suspect turns off support for both normal arrays and associative arrays. There is no way to turn off just associative arrays, as far as I can tell.

Much more likely, your script starts with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

which, on macOS, is Bash 3.2 without associative arrays; the fix is to use

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43948526/3266847) for details and more alternatives.