# How to escape keys having a hyphen in associated array

Tags: linux, bash, dictionary

I want to create a map in bash where some of the map-keys may have values containing a hyphen (`-`)

I've tried following code

```
declare -a buckets
buckets["us-east-1"]="bucketname-us-east-1";

region="us-east-1"
buckets[$region]="bucketname-us-east-1"; 

# both of them throws buckets["us-east-2"]: bad array subscript

buckets["us\-east\-1"]="bucketname-us-east-1"; 
# throws syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "\-east\-1")
```

Is there any other way of creating the map?

Comment: `-a` is for regular arrays (integer index). `-A` is for associative arrays.

Comment: I already tried that sorry for not being clear I was using mac os high sierra and it seems -A option works with bash v4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash 4 associative arrays: error "declare: -A: invalid option"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047648/bash-4-associative-arrays-error-declare-a-invalid-option)

Answer (score 5):

As Wumpus stated in the comments, the problem is that you've declared a regular, numerically-indexed [array](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Arrays), when you clearly wanted an associative array. In the context of a numerically-indexed array, indices are [arithmetic expressions](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion), which can result in confusing errors, or no errors when you might expect an error!

```
$ declare -a foo
$ foo[abc-def]=bar
```

This is legal, but does not assign "bar" to the index "abc-def". It assigns "bar" to the index 0, which is what `abc`, `def` and `abc-def` all expand to, since they are not assigned. In other words, you're subtracting 0 from 0.

```
$ echo "${foo[0]}"
bar
```

If you try to escape the dashes you get an error, like the one you saw.

```
$ echo $(( abc \- def ))
bash: abc \- def : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "\- def ")
```

But you can use an associative array here, instead:

```
$ declare -A bar
$ bar[abc-def]=xyzzy
$ echo "${bar[abc-def]}"
xyzzy
```

This allows you to use strings in array indices, and they do not resolve to arithmetic expressions.

Edit: `bad array subscript`

I didn't see the *bad array subscript* at first, because you only get that on the first assignment to the array.

```
$ unset foo
$ foo[-1]=bad
bash: foo[-1]: bad array subscript

$ foo[0]=whatevz
$ foo[-1]=bad
$ # no error!
```

Comment: Brilliant ! As an aside, you may need to stress the fact that variable expansion and arithmetic operations do happen inside the array index operator even if the index is double quoted as in `"us-east-1"`. That expands to `0-0-1` had the variables `us` and `east` were not assigned yet.  Since a negative index can be used only to access an element and not to write values, the op got a `bad-subscript` error. The op would have got away had it been just `"us-east"`. This is indeed a new revelation for me :-). Correct me if I am wrong.