# Bad Substitution error on Bash while changing case of string

Tags: bash, terminal, parameters

I'm a beginner to BASH and I'm trying to practice parameter expansion. Here are some commands that constantly seem to error out and I'm not able figure this out.
I am running a recent version of BASH so, that might not be the issue.

```
(base) Ritviks-Macbook-Pro:~ ritviksainarayanan$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.21(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin23.0.0)
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

(base) Ritviks-Macbook-Pro:~ ritviksainarayanan$ foo="mYnAME"

(base) Ritviks-Macbook-Pro:~ ritviksainarayanan$ echo ${foo}

mYnAME

(base) Ritviks-Macbook-Pro:~ ritviksainarayanan$ echo ${foo^}

-bash: ${foo^}: bad substitution
```

Comment: What does `echo $BASH_VERSION` show?

Comment: I get that error in the default MacOS bash, which is 3.x. I suspect you're not running the newer version of bash as your login shell.

Comment: Your suspicion was correct. Although I have a more recent version of Bash installed, the default is 3.x. Any suggestions on how I can change this?
ritviksainarayanan$ echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.57(1)-release

Comment: In Terminal preferences you should be able to choose the specific path to `bash`.

Comment: [Associative arrays: error "declare: -A: invalid option"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6047648/3266847) handles this exact scenario. (Edit: or not... [this](https://itnext.io/upgrading-bash-on-macos-7138bd1066ba) is a good article about upgrading your Bash version correctly.)

Comment: You can use `chsh` to change your default login shell, Terminal uses that by default.

Comment: FYI, I tried it with bash 5.2 and it works.  I have installed this bash using homebrew.